# Sorting queryset of search result and render back thru ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, django, django-templates

I am stuck with this problem: I have a search result page in which there are several results. I want the user to be able to sort the results depending on some criteria. I am doing this in AJAX. The problem is how to render the sorted data coming from the server to fields again.

```
function sort(){
    var sortid = $('#sort').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/sort/",
        data: { sortid: sortid },
    }).done(function(data){
        // how to render this sorted 'data' back to <td>s?  
    });
}
```

this is my binding code:

```
<select onchange="sort()" id="sort">   
    <option>price</option>
    <option>rate</option>
</select>
```

this is the result place:

```
<tr class="result">
    <td>
        <li>{{loc.locationname}}</li>
    </td>
    <td>    
        <li>{{loc.rating}}</li>
    </td>
    <td>
        <li>{{loc.price}}</li>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: what is the result of your ajax call?

Comment: @Chris, sorted queryset coming from server. i just want to know the way how to render back to ``td``'s

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, it is easy to see this in my code: ``<option>price</option> <option>rate</option>``

Comment: @doniyor Yeah I just saw it. Your HTML is invalid BTW - you can only have `li` elements within `ol` or `ul`, not `td`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, yeah thanks, i know, but this is not the problem now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view can return a rendered snippet like which you can just render into a div on the client side

Your ajax call can look like this

```
function sort(){
    var sortid = $('#sort').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/sort/",
        data: { sortid: sortid },
    }).done(function(data){
         $('#results-div').html(data.html);
    });
}
```

A example view

```
import json
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader, RequestContext


def my_view(request, query=None):
    # trivialized example

    sortid = request.REQUEST.get('sortid')

    # you might want to store the results into cache 
    results = MyModel.objects.filter(name__icontains=query).order_by(sortid)

    if request.is_ajax():
       t = loader.get_template('search_results.html')
       html = t.render(RequestContext({'results': results))
       return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'html': html}))
    # handle the other cases here
```

inside of `search_results.html` you will just render the results into your table

```
{% for loc in results %}
<tr class="result">
    <td>
        <li>{{loc.locationname}}</li>
    </td>
    <td>    
        <li>{{loc.rating}}</li>
    </td>
    <td>
        <li>{{loc.price}}</li>
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks, this should work. but this is not different than ``render_to_response``,

Answer (score 1):

```
 function(data){
   var tablehtml='<tbody>'
   $.each(data,function(i,res) {
       tablehtml+='<tr class="result">'+
                   '<td><li>'+res.locationname+'</li></td>'+
                   //...
       });
    $("table").html(tablehtml+'</tbody'>)
    }
```

nb: i've added tbody tag because this way of adding html is way faster if the html is wrapped in a single parent than if it is a (long) list of nodes

euh... edit but to use this you need to tell in the .ajax that you are expecting a json response (`datatype:'json'`) which is not the case right now

also  you'll need to send a specific header("content-type:application/json") from the server

if you insist on sending html then parse the data on server side (wrap it) and append it at once in the callback

if you want to reconsider your sorting feature concept, if data is not so big & if you can gzip; i'd load at once all data & do the sorting in js (no more server call the feature will be way way faster for the user : little more wait on page load but instantaneous sorting then after

Comment: I think he's getting HTML back though, not JSON.

Comment: yeah saw it just now, my bad, however in this case json seems more appropriate

Comment: I agree. It would make the sorting much more straightforward. All you'd need to do is amend the DOM to add the data from the JSON once sorted.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan depending on the size of the data (<150kb pre gz) i would indeed load it at once & do the sorting from the client

Comment: I assume that's what you meant by `this is the result place`

Comment: Fair enough, so what data type are you getting back then? It would be very relevant information you should have put in the question.